# How to solve: -bash: : cannot execute binary file

Tags: macos, bash, binary-files

I have a file named b1 that contains assembly language. I am trying to execute the file on OSX using

```
$ ./b1
```

I get the following error:

```
-bash: ./b1: cannot execute binary file
```

I've looked at other similar questions, but to no avail. I'm definitely using a 64 bit architecture.

Here are output of relevant info:

```
$ file b1
b1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
$ uname -a
Darwin Anthonys-MacBook-Pro.local 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Edit:

Ran `as b1` which ended up terminating with: 
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/as: fatal error in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Sorry, this file is for GNU/Linux

According to your `file` output, this program is for GNU/Linux. I know this because:

1. The file `b1` is in the [`ELF` (Extensible and Linkable Format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format, while Mac OS X uses the `Mach-O` format for binaries;
2. `file` recognizes this file is for `GNU/Linux 2.6.18`, meaning it'll work on most modern Linux distributions.

To solve your problem, you must either run this problem within a Linux distribution, recompile the program, or get the Mac OS X version of this program.

## So... Why doesn't `b1` work on *XYZ* OS or CPU?

Just as people speak different languages, different computers understand different instructions. For instance, your Mac uses an Intel processor, while your Android phone uses an ARM processor. Compare these two processors to English and French. They may belong to the same language family, but still, you can't speak both at the same time. This leads to a conclusion:

> Dissimilar computers "talk" in different tongues.

As for why different operating systems (such as Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux) can't use the same binaries, consider this:

> What makes software objectively different to hardware? Not much.

Both provide a system and a "language" that allows for more complex components of the computer to complete tasks for the end user. Both require an agreed language to get work done. Imagine if there were 10 people in a shouting match, each speaking a different language. This is why different OS software need different binaries, even if both operating systems use the same processor.

Comment: Hi, I have similar problem trying to compile elf file in Mac OS 10.9. Could you please tell me how to run this onmac

Comment: AllsWell you found a way for this!?

Answer (score 1):

assembly language? You need to compile it, or rather assemble it.

```
man as
```

Comment: The questioner seems to have conflated _assembly language_ and _machine code_.  See the output of `file` in the question.