# How can I resolve the error “cannot execute binary file”?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I'm trying to test my installation for [Pickit 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PICKit) on my Mac for the first time 
and when I put in: `pk2cmd -?v`
I get:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pk2cmd: cannot execute binary file
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please, try to see if this link is helpfull:
http://curuxa.org/en/Pk2cmd_manual_installation
or this:
http://www.waveguide.se/?article=programming-pics-using-the-pickit2-and-pk2cmd

Answer (score 0):

You have a binary executable file `pk2cmd` for a different architecture than Mac OS X. This system uses executables in the format `Mach-O`.

You can check the format of your executable using this command:

```
file /usr/local/bin/pk2cmd
```

See also this question: [How to solve: -bash: : cannot execute binary file](https://superuser.com/q/724301/61370).

Comment: The software was released both for Linux and Mac OS X. See [New PICkit 2 PK2CMD v1.20 for Linux & Mac OS X Released](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m396218.aspx). You probably downloaded the binaries for Linux instead of Mac OS X.

Comment: This is what i get after I put in "file /usr/local/bin/pk2cmd" = \/usr/local/bin/pk2cmd: data

Comment: the link youve sent me leads me to the pickit2 product which I already have and runs perfectly in my uni computers(Microsoft). you saying that I have to buy a completely different Pickit to run on my MAC?

Comment: @ChineduLloydAbalogu, there is also a different possibility - that the binary executable file content is corrupted. For example on [nmap executable binary](http://nmap.org/download.html#macosx) (extracted from the downloaded `nmap-6.47.dmg`) I get: `file -k nmap` `nmap: Mach-O i386 executable`. How did you install the package? Was not the file `.dmg` originally. Did not you just rename it? ------ To your second comment: I have no slightest idea how is Pickit 2 being sold and distributed. :)